# How can I "unpivot" specific columns from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, melt

I have a pandas DataFrame, eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'farm' : ['A','B','A','B'], 
                   'fruit':['apple','apple','pear','pear'], 
                   '2014':[10,12,6,8], 
                   '2015':[11,13,7,9]})
```

ie:

```
   2014  2015 farm  fruit
0    10    11    A  apple
1    12    13    B  apple
2     6     7    A   pear
3     8     9    B   pear
```

How can I convert it to the following?

```
  farm  fruit  value  year
0    A  apple     10  2014
1    B  apple     12  2014
2    A   pear      6  2014
3    B   pear      8  2014
4    A  apple     11  2015
5    B  apple     13  2015
6    A   pear      7  2015
7    B   pear      9  2015
```

I have tried `stack` and `unstack` but haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Melt is an awesome name for this function

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This can be done with `pd.melt()`:

```
# value_name is 'value' by default, but setting it here to make it clear
pd.melt(x, id_vars=['farm', 'fruit'], var_name='year', value_name='value')
```

Result:

```
  farm  fruit  year  value
0    A  apple  2014     10
1    B  apple  2014     12
2    A   pear  2014      6
3    B   pear  2014      8
4    A  apple  2015     11
5    B  apple  2015     13
6    A   pear  2015      7
7    B   pear  2015      9

[8 rows x 4 columns]
```

I'm not sure how common "melt" is as the name for this kind of operation, but that's what it's called in R's `reshape2` package, which probably inspired the name here.

Comment: Incredibly easy and awesome name - melt! Thanks a lot!

Comment: 'melt' does it incredibly well.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using `stack()`; just that `set_index()` has to be called first to repeat `farm` and `fruit` for each year-value pair.

```py
long_df = df.set_index(['farm', 'fruit']).rename_axis(columns='year').stack().reset_index(name='value')
```

[image: result1]

Also `melt` is a DataFrame method as well, so it can be called like:

```py
long_df = df.melt(id_vars=['farm', 'fruit'], var_name='year', value_name='value')
```

One interesting function is `pd.wide_to_long` which can also be used to "melt" a frame. However, it requires a `stubname`, so wouldn't work for the case in the OP but works for other cases. For example, in the case below (note how years in the column labels have `value_` in it).

```py
long_df = pd.wide_to_long(df, 'value', i=['farm', 'fruit'], j='year', sep='_').reset_index()
```

[image: result2]